# Does granting a dhcp lease require a wifi passord

Tags: networking

I may be confusing two things here but can anyone tell me if when a device is granted a lease by a router it needs to provide the router wifi network password or is the lease granted (or not) and then the password is required in order to 'use' the wifi network. The reason for asking is that our router reports on all leases that are granted and I'm trying to understand if these grants are subject to the device supplying the router wifi password or whether they could be from any passing traffic which has no interest in using our network i.e. someone with a phone just passing in the street.

Answer (score 4):

DHCP is an application layer protocol, so it is only accessible by wireless devices that have authenticated to your network. Therefore, if a device has not provided your router with a password, it cannot obtain a lease.

Answer (score 0):

When you connect a device to a wired Ethernet port, the link has to come up (be established) between the two devices before any communication takes place. So DHCP discovers are not sent by the client until after this point.

With wireless, the connection establishment is a bit more complex, however the same principle applies. Part of the link establishment in wireless will require that any authentication is done prior to a client sending any sort of traffic. So DHCP discovers are not sent by the client until after they are fully connected to the wireless network (including authentication, establishing encryption, etc).